# jQuery toggle hides selector

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I want to use the jQuery `toggle()` function to slide an off-screen div (`#mobileNav`) in from the left when an element (`#mobileMenu`) is clicked and then when the element is clicked again, the div slides off-screen again. I've got the sliding working on click, but the trigger element is then hidden - a `display: none` is injected into the tag - which makes it impossible to click again slide the div back out. Here's the relevant code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#mobileMenu').click(function() {
        $("#mobileMenu").toggle(function() {
            $('#mobileNav', this).animate({left: '0' });
        }, function() {
            $("#mobileNav", this).animate({left: '-380px'});
        });
    });
});
```

`#mobileNav` is initially set to `left: -380px`.

```
<div class="mobile-menu-icon">
    <p><a id="mobileMenu" href="#">&#9776;</a></p>
</div>
```

The answer may use scoping, but I can't seem to grasp how that works.

As always - thanks for any and all help - Joe

Comment: `toggle` event method was deprecated and removed from latest versions of jQuery. The method is probably the `toggle` effect method which does a different thing. It shows/hides an element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is because the `toggle()` method no longer works in the manner you are expecting. The 'toggle between functions' signature was [deprecated in 1.8 and removed in 1.9](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/).

Instead you need to handle the change in behaviour yourself. In this case, by checking the current `left` position of the element:

```
$('#mobileMenu').click(function() {
    $(this).toggle(function() {
        var leftPos = parseInt($(this).css('left'), 10) == 0 ? '-380px' : 0;
        $('#mobileNav').animate({ left: leftPos });
    });
});
```

Alternatively, and preferably, you could perform the animation in CSS and just use `toggleClass` to trigger it:

```css
#mobileNav {
    left: 0;
    transition: left 0.5s;
}
#mobileNav.open {
    left: -380px;
}
```

```js
$('#mobileMenu').click(function() {
    $('#mobileNav').toggleClass('open');
});
```

Finally, note that your use of a contextual `id` selector (`$("#mobileNav", this)`) is redundant as id attributes should be unique within a document, therefore the context selector is moot.

Comment: Thanks, Rory. I went with your alternative approach - much cleaner! I did end up reversing the left values, because I want the default to be off-screen, but that worked well. Cheers! Also, thanks so much for the explanation about the deprecation. That explains why I kept reading conflicting descriptions.

Comment: No problem, glad to help